# Error in phpcloud uploading zf2 with MySQL connection

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

My php ZendFramework2 code is running well in local, but when I commit it to php-cloud, it is showing database connection error. 
Please check the page here-> http://roommates.my.phpcloud.com/roommate/album/index

Does ZF2 need an application.ini file? No idea how to proceed..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is using a local pipe connection to your mysql server. If the mysql server is running locally, on the same server as your code, and currently up. Your connection information should work. Otherwise your application.ini file needs to specify connection information for mysql.

Comment: I am using ZF2. Do we need a separate application.ini file here, or we can use application.config.php file?

Comment: I've worked alot with ZF1, the standard at that point was to specific different settings for each environment. I assume the standard is similar, and all you need to do is add settings for your new environment.